# Restrict users view/access the default databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-word, ssms

I have a user set up in SQL Server Management Studio whose user mapping is set so they can only access the 'ReportServer' database.

When I connect to my SQL Server through MS Word, I am given the following options for databases to connect to:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chOJo.jpg)

I do not want this user to have access to, or even be able to see the master, tempdb or msdb databases, and I have not got them selected in the user mapping for this user. How can I set it up so the user can't see these databases?

Answer (score 0):

Use DENY View..

```
  DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO testuser;
```

***Steps in general include..***
1.Create login with default database
2.create user for that login in all databases
3.Deny view

```
  DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO testuser;
```

**step1:**
//create login with default database

```
1.USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN loginame FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE='testdb'
GO
```

**step2:**
2.create user in all databases..

```
use testdb
create user username for loginname
```

Now You can assign Permissions to that user like read,write... and by default this user will be shown only one database..

**Step3:**

```
  DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO testuser;--this should be repeated in all databases which you wish to hide from user..
```

if you have aleady existing login..Then you can change default login for that user like below..

```
Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='login', @defdb='testdb'
```

**References:**
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2995/how-to-hide-sql-server-user-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: Hi there. This helped get rid of the msdb. but the master and tempdb are still there. You mentioned I should repeat that code in all databases I want to hide, but sql studio tells me I can only use it while in the master db.

Comment: for creating login ,it should be master DB.For TempDB you dont need to create login,by default all users will have login.So i recommend creating windows group for all users which you can use with mail merge and do the stuff on this.